# JBoss EAP 7 - NoTxConnection does not release managed connection

Tags: jboss-eap-7

We are using JBoss eap 7 application server with custom LDAP resource adapter implementation in NoTransaction mode.
When managed connection is unable to create physical connection and throws an Exception, jboss does not release managed connection back to pool and that leads to connection leak.
Such issue does not happen with transaction connection. Is this behavior intentional or is it bug in JBoss JCA?

StackTrace

```
javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/PCELDAPConnectionFactory
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:656)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:563)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
....
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:566)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:617)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:589)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:590)
```

Thanks

Comment: What the exception stack trace says about?

Comment: Exception thrown is
javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])

Comment: IJ000453 / IJ000655 errors indicate that the entire population of the JBoss managed connection pool is in-use and no more connections can be created to service additional requests due to the configured (or implicit default) max-pool-size value.

- The two most common causes of this error are (1) pools that are not configured with a large enough max-pool-size to handle high loads and (2) failure of application components to close connections (returning them to the pool for reuse) when they are finished using them.

Comment: 1# Make sure that your datasource("java:/PCELDAPConnectionFactory") should have fault tolerant/connection validation enabled as per[1].
[1]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/single/configuration_guide/index#configure_database_connection_validation_settings

2# You may need to increase the max-pool-size of datasource pool("java:/PCELDAPConnectionFactory")to allow for a greater number of users according to your system behavior / business requirement..

Comment: 3# Make sure that you should need to configure "idle-timeout-minutes" as per your convenient business/application requirement for datasource pool ("java:/PCELDAPConnectionFactory").
4#Make sure to verify that the database server side timeout value is *larger* than the timeout period in JBoss EAP.. Allowing JBoss to gracefully timeout connections rather than setting up the circumstance where connections in the pool may be externally invalidated

Comment: Yes timeout is configured and pool size is enough for this type of connection. As this is good It still does not give me what I need so I implemented handling of this situation simply by releasing ManagedConnection from Physical connection creation like:
`javax.resource.spi.ConnectionEventListener#connectionClosed(ConnectionEvent)`

Comment: Not only timeout.. Read and apply all the above 3 comments# and also attached the documentation. Apply all the changes in DS pool (java:/PCELDAPConnectionFactory).